# CI cannot download gradle distribution snapshot

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our CI suddenly fails with the following error message:

```
$ ./gradlew clean jar --stacktrace -i --no-daemon
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-6.8-20201019220035+0000-bin.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions-snapshots/gradle-6.8-20201019220035+0000-bin.zip
```

I don't unterstand why the distribution file is not found anymore and how can we fix it? I tried clearing all caches but it fails with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

There was a new gradle release on that day and upgrade the gradle wrapper solved the issue:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.8.1
```

(remember to run this command twice to really update the complete wrapper)

Comment: Just don't rely on snapshot versions. Unless referencing a snapshot, it will not try to fetch it.